# parse error when trying to get json from api - dialogflow

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, request, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to get json data from the iex api. I am using the inline editor for googles dialogflow and when trying to get the json from the api, I keep getting the error:

```
Error: Parse Error
at Error (native)
at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:363:20)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:559:20)
```

The console log shows that I'm requesting the correct path to get the json request (in this case I wanted the microsoft json info

```
API Request: api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/MSFT/company
```

I am not sure why the json is not getting read in correctly but I think the error is occurring because the body var of my code is not receiving information from http request. I'm just not sure what is wrong with my code.

Here is my code:

```
'use strict';

const http = require('http');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const host = 'api.iextrading.com';

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((req, res)     => {
  // Get the company
  let company = req.body.queryResult.parameters['company_name']; // city is a required param

  // Call the iex API
  callCompanyApi(company).then((output) => {
    res.json({ 'fulfillmentText': output }); 
  }).catch(() => {
    res.json({ 'fulfillmentText': `I don't know this company`});
  });
});

function callCompanyApi (company) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Create the path for the HTTP request to get the company
    let path = '/1.0/stock/' + company + '/company';
    console.log('API Request: ' + host + path);

    // Make the HTTP request to get the company info
    http.get({host: host, path: path}, (res) => {
    let body = ''; // var to store the response chunks
    res.on('data', (d) => { body += d; });// store each response chunk
    res.on('end', () => {
    // After all the data has been received parse the JSON for desired data
        console.log(body);
        let response = JSON.parse(body);
        let description = response['description'];

    // Create response
        let output = `${description}`

    // Resolve the promise with the output text
        console.log(output);
        resolve(output);
      });
      res.on('error', (error) => {
      console.log(`Error calling the iex API: ${error}`)
      reject();
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Inline Dialogflow Editor, then you're running on Cloud Functions for Firebase (or Firebase Cloud Functions). By default, there is a restriction on the base plan that you cannot make network calls outside of Google's network.

To get around this, you can upgrade your Firebase plan to a subscription such as the [Blaze Plan](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/). This does require a credit card on file, however the base level of usage should be part of the free tier.

You can also run your webhook anywhere else, as long as there is a web server with a valid SSL certificate that can handle HTTPS requests. If you want to run it locally, you can even use something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.io/).

Comment: I’m actually on the blaze plan so that shouldn’t be the issue